# USB Type-C/Lightning 4 vs Mini Display Port 1.4

Tags: displayport

My laptop has **USB Type-C/Lightning 4** and **Display Port 1.4** ports.

Is there a difference in which port to use to connect to an external monitor?

The external monitor supports Display Port 1.4. Its resolution is 3440x1440, HDR, 10bit colours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DP 1.4 handles 8K at 60 frames at 10-bit color only with display stream compression. So essentially it's a dedicated port for your monitor with audio support upto 192KHz and 7.1 surround sound support. It has a dedicated controller on the motherboard is designed to handle displays. I believe you can set it up with a daisy chain to add 1 more monitor at up to 4k.

Type-C Based Thunderbolt 4 uses USB-C Alt Mode to support 8K monitors with the same specifications as DP, but daisy chain capabilities of up to 6 monitors I believe. Due to its PD capabilities, you might even be able to power your laptop using a supporting monitor.

However, as we are in the repair industry, the amount of Type-C PD controller failures we see is ridiculous which can fundamentally create a problem with charging or other issues with your motherboard (especially if you plug and unplug it regularly).

So my recommendation would be to use the dedicated display port (which we have never had to repair before, unless in cases of liquid damage or physical damage).